# flutter error in a non-null string must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

this error is in udemy maximilian schwarzmuller's flutter course error.
this is the code: I have provided the string value still I getting nonnull string provided to text widget error in ('tx.title'),

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './transaction.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyWidget());

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'flutter app',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> transactions = [
    Transaction(
      id: '01',
      title: 'azeem',
      amount: 90.98,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      id: '02',
      title: 'azeem',
      amount: 90.98,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    )
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Expense App'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Card(
              child: Text('Text_1'),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: transactions.map((tx) {
              return Card(
                child: Text(tx.title),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have provided the string to this function but I am getting an error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAuIp.png)

Comment: Please show the Transaction class.

Comment: `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Transaction {
  String id;
  String name;
  double amount;
  DateTime date;

  Transaction(
    {
    @required id,
    @required name,
    @required amount,
    @required date});
}
@patrick`

Comment: This code does not compile: the instance fields are not initialized. This is probably the cause of your error.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
  Column(
        children: transactions.map((tx) {
          return Card(
            child: Text(tx.title ?? "default text on null"),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
```

Comment: but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to solve this problem

**1.**

```
Column(
        children: transactions.map((tx) {
          return Card(
            child: Text(tx.title!= null ? tx.title : "Default Title"),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
```

**2.**

```
Column(
        children: transactions.map((tx) {
          return Card(
            child: Text(tx.title ?? "Default Title"),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
```

**3.**

```
if(tx.title != null)
Column(
        children: transactions.map((tx) {
          return Card(
            child: Text(tx.title!),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
```

**4.**

```
Column(
        children: transactions.map((tx) {
          return Card(
            child: Text(tx.title.toString()),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
```

Comment: `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Transaction {
  String id;
  String name;
  double amount;
  DateTime date;

  Transaction(
    {
    @required id,
    @required name,
    @required amount,
    @required date});
}`
@patrick

Comment: there is string data with name title in transaction list

Comment: i have just changed 'title' into 'name', but problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The Transaction's title field is probably not initialized. Are you using a null-safe Dart version? Your Transaction class should look like this:

```
class Transaction {
  String id;
  String name;
  double amount;
  DateTime date;
  Transaction({required this.id, required this.name, required this.amount, required this.date});
}
```